# NumberFormatException Error

Tags: java, date-format, numberformatexception

Hi i get the following error:

```
2014-09-26T14:17:40.779-0300|Grave: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException' recebido ao invocar escuta de a��o '#{comentario.cancelarAtendimento}' para o componente 'j_idt140'
2014-09-26T14:17:40.780-0300|Grave: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

i created this formatter :

```
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, new Locale("pt", "BR"));
```

and i want to retrive the date from the session in this way :

```
if (sessao.getAttribute("dataInicial") != null)
        {

            dataInicial = (String) sessao.getAttribute("dataInicial");


            dataIni = new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse(dataInicial).getTime());

        }
```

then i pass the dataIni here

```
 ocorrencias = cadastradorOcorrecia.pesquisarAvancada(usuario.getCodigo(), Integer.parseInt(pesqCodigo), pesquisaCliente, pesquisaStatus, pesquisaDepartamento, pesquisaSolicitante, pesquisaUltimoAtend, pesquisaSistema, dataIni, dataFi, pesquisaCriador,Integer.parseInt(pesquisaProduto),Integer.parseInt(pesquisaModulo));
```

here i get the numberFormatException ---> Can anyone have an idea of what i´m doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

and then it goes to the dao instance for retrive the information with the database.

Comment: What is the value of `dataInicial`?  Empty String?

Comment: in this case is null

Comment: If it was null your Formatter will give NullPointerException.. If it is empty it will be ParseException.. You are getting a NumberFormatException

Comment: @gtgaxiola if it is null it will still throw a NumberFormatException.

Comment: i put this       System.out.println("Data Inicialllllllllll" + dataInicial);

Comment: and i recived 2014-09-26T14:48:25.190-0300|Informações: Data Inicialllllllllll

Comment: now i got 2014-09-26T15:00:32.178-0300|Grave: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""

Answer (score 1):

The Integer.parseInt throws NumberFormatException if it cannot convert a string into integer. In your case I would check the values of pesqCodigo, pesquisaProduto & pesquisaModulo.

JavaDoc for [Integer.parseInt(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Examples

```
Integer.parseInt(" 234"); ---> Throws NumberFormatException as it has space
Integer.parseInt(""); ---> Throws NumberFormatException as it is not parseable for an integer
Integer.parseInt(null); ---> Throws NumberFormatException and not npe
Integer.parseInt(" 234 ".trim()); ---> Doesnt throw NumberFormatException as it trims before trying to parse it.
```

**Edit:**

It is not surprising that it does not work. This would probably work better:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                            Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Then to print with your required format you need a second SimpleDateFormat:

```
Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(date);
SimpleDateFormat print = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(print.format(parsedDate));
```

Notes:
you should include the locale as if your locale is not English, the day name might not be recognised
IST is ambiguous and can lead to problems so you should use the proper time zone name if possible in your input.

Comment: now i got 2014-09-26T15:00:32.178-0300|Grave: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""

Comment: @marco please read the java doc for date parse to understand why this error occurs it will be much faster for you to resolve the issue than keep asking on SO. Check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of `pesqCodigo`, `pesquisaProduto` or `pesquisaModulo` is a String that does not represent a number.

I think there is no relation with `dataInicial`, as a `DateFormat` shouldn't throw a `NumberFormatException`. The Integer.parseInt() methods can throw this Exception, so just have a look at the use of that function.

Comment: 2014-09-26T15:00:32.178-0300|Grave: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""

Comment: You say in your question that you have a NumberFormatException... : "here i get the numberFormatException ---> Can anyone have an idea of what i´m doing wrong?". AND it is the title of the question!!!